# getNextEntry() doesn't display folder as an entry?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unzip

Hi I'm new to android programming.

I'm trying to create a program to unzip a zipped file in my sd card and I noticed something when I debug.

```
public void testZipOrder() throws Exception {
            File file = new File(_zipFile);
            zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            ZipEntry entry = null;
            while ( (entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null ) {
             System.out.println( entry.getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

this give me an output of :

```
06-27 00:42:06.360: I/System.out(15402): weee.txt
06-27 00:42:06.360: I/System.out(15402): hi/bye.txt
06-27 00:42:06.360: I/System.out(15402): hi/hiwayne.txt
```

isn't it suppose to give

```
weee.txt
hi/
hi/bye.txt
hi/hiwayne.txt
```

or something that displays its folder instead?

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println( entry.isDirectory());` in your while loop to see if it contains the directory at all. It may be that only files return a string for getName().

Comment: It gave me : 
'weee.txt,
 false,
 hi/bye.txt,
 false,
 hi/hiwayne.txt,
  false'

:(

Comment: In that case I suspect that there is a problem with the zip file itself. It must not contain an entry for the directory.

Comment: from what i tested out , they only display hi/someotherfolder/ , they dont display the first folder as hi/ in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on my own environment using a test zip file created with 7zip and the following method:

```
public void testZipOrder() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("zip.zip");
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    ZipEntry entry = null;
    while ( (entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null ) {
     System.out.println( entry.getName());
    }
    zis.close();
}
```

Note this method is effectively identical to yours.

The resulting output was:

```
file1.txt
folder1/
folder1/file2.txt
folder1/folder2/
folder1/folder2/file3.txt
```

Which is, I believe, what you are looking for. As such I expect the problem is with the zip file itself, not your code. It is likely that your zip file does not contain an entry for the directory "hi/".

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#Structure) for a basic description of how zip files are structured.

Answer (score 0):

> ZIP spec does not require the ordered "placement" of the file and its parent(s) directory in the zip file, and in fact the parent directory entries can be totally absent

See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054027